# Codeigniter : Attempt to read property "status" on array

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i'm trying to make a condition where if the `$lowongan->status == 'active'`, it will show the rows of data that has a `active` status, but i got the error message : `Attempt to read property "status" on array`
How can i fix this??

The model :

```
public function show_lowongan(){
        return $this->db->get('lowongan');
    }
```

The Controller :

```
public function lowongan()
    {
        $data['lowongan'] = $this->m_lowongan->show_lowongan()->result();
        $this->load->view('lowongan', $data);
    }
```

The view :

```
<div class="row">
          <?php if($lowongan->status == "draft"){?>
            <?php
              $no = 1;
              foreach($lowongan as $lowong){
            ?>
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5><?php echo $lowong->title?></h5>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->lokasi?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->created_at?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->level_pekerja?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->pengalaman_kerja?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->pendidikan?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->alamat?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->no_wa?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->no_telp?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->min_gaji?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->max_gaji?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->job_desc?></p>
                  <button><a href="<?php echo base_url('lowongan/detail/'.$lowong->id)?>">Detail Lowongan</a></button>
                  <button><a href="<?php echo base_url('lowongan/edit/'.$lowong->id)?>">Edit Lowongan</a></button>
                  <button><a href="<?php echo base_url('lowongan/delete/'.$lowong->id)?>">Hapus Lowongan</a></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php }?>
          <?php }else{?>
            Sorry No Job Posting
          <?php }?>
        </div>
```

Comment: `result()` generates an empty or 2d array (array of objects also known as an objectArray). There is no `status` property in the first level -- the second level objects contain the status properties.

Comment: If you are filtering on status,  do that in your model.  It is not the view's job to filter/process data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two conditions are required

1. To check the total count of jobs `if(count($lowongan) > 0)` OR `if (!$lowongan)`
2. To check the status for each of the $lowong. `if($lowong->status == "draft")`

You have placed the `if` condition above the `for` loop it should be below that so that you can access the single `$lowong` and further its `$lowong->status` like below:

```
<div class="row">
          <?php if(count($lowongan) > 0){?>
            <?php
              $no = 1;
              foreach($lowongan as $lowong){
            ?>
            <?php if($lowong->status == "draft"){?>
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5><?php echo $lowong->title?></h5>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->lokasi?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->created_at?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->level_pekerja?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->pengalaman_kerja?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->pendidikan?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->alamat?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->no_wa?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->no_telp?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->min_gaji?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->max_gaji?></p>
                  <p><?php echo $lowong->job_desc?></p>
                  <button><a href="<?php echo base_url('lowongan/detail/'.$lowong->id)?>">Detail Lowongan</a></button>
                  <button><a href="<?php echo base_url('lowongan/edit/'.$lowong->id)?>">Edit Lowongan</a></button>
                  <button><a href="<?php echo base_url('lowongan/delete/'.$lowong->id)?>">Hapus Lowongan</a></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php }
              }?>
          <?php }else{?>
            Sorry No Job Posting
          <?php }?>
        </div>
```

Comment: `if(count($lowongan) > 0)` can be simplified to `if (!$lowongan) {` because empty arrays are "falsey".

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa you are right. I'll add that too

Comment: Owh my goodness, thank you so much sir for the help it works really well :D